# Align ImageView to right

Tags: android, layout

I need to align a the imageview to the right. It seems the easiest thing in the world, but I can't do it ( arg!!! I hate android layout !!!) How can I do???

PS : If I could manage that the textview and the ImageView were aligned vertically, it would be very nice !

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/TuComentario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_myComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_text"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/smallpadding_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/tucomentario"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_big" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rev_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_myComment"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="editar comentario"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/smallpadding_text"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tx in advance !

Answer (score 0):

it s not  alignParentRight="t" you need change like alignParentRight="true"

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="t"
```

you need to go like this:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

For aligning them verticaly them try using this on the imagebutton:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/title_mycomment
```

Comment: no, I want them both on the same line, maybe I wasn't explaining well

Comment: try using this on the button layout  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title_myComment"

Comment: Not working ! image keeps showing centered... It doesn't do on the corner.

Comment: you need to remove android:layout_centerVertical="true"